# Writing R demos for a package

Tags: r, devtools, r-package, roxygen2

I have a very simple question really. There's a demo function `demo()` i.e. `demo(scoping)` which runs a demo of the topic. How do I write something like this for my own package? Its crazy but I have tried googling for any documentation related to it but there is none available (either that or my googling skills suck big time). I tried the documentation for devtools and roxygen too but maybe I missed it.

Can anyone point me in a right direction? Are there any packages which can generate it during the package installation? Or do I have to write it manually (I'm totally fine with that but right now I have zero information on this).

And yes, I would want to be able to do it in R console (not rstudio).

Comment: See http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/demo.html. Basically just .R scripts in a `demo/` folder.

Comment: [search](https://github.com/cran/LearnBayes/tree/master/demo) for [packages](https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/tree/dev/demo) with [demos](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/tree/master/demo)

Comment: The link @Marius provided also makes a good point that demos aren't really that useful---vignettes are superior because they are listed on CRAN (and therefore easy to find), are checked for correctness on package build (so you know when they break), and can include both outputs and narrative explanation (so users don't have to actually run the example to understand what's going on).

Comment: Though this question is nearly [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (*recommend ... an off-site resource*), I think it's relevant and still quite useful for follow-on readers. And while Marius' link addresses the *question*, I feel that mikeck's comment and Alec's answer address the implied *need*, which is to facilitate interactive demonstration of concepts within a package. (I further suggest that r-console as a strict necessity is unfortunate, though a good "Rmd" vignette can still be copied and pasted to a console.)

Comment: There's nothing that requires Rmd docs be authored in RStudio. The template and shortcuts are handy, but you could write it in any text editor you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `roxygen2` does not allow you to create demos, it does allow you to include special `@examples` within the documentation[[1](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#man-functions)]. These showup in your function or object help pages and can even be run automatically upon loading the package to test for functioning dependencies, or they can just serve as examples to your end users.

`devtools` on the other hand offers *vignettes* which is a "long-form guide to your package"[[2](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html)]. These can be accessed through your overall package documentation and actually linked to anywhere within your documentation. You can make multiple vignettes and make them function or work-flow specific, organized by function family or something similar.

If you are adamant about using demos, you'll have to manually go through the trouble of establishing the proper directories, formatting and testing the demo files. If you do intend to go down this path, Hadley Wickham has some *very* sparse documentation on the subject here: [[3](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/demo.html)].

Comment: More the point: a vignette written as Rmarkdown is (in my opinion) a little more convenient in that I can open it and edit it directly in my R-browser of choice, interacting with it; vignettes that are strictly pdf can still be copied but add a layer of indirection that is just less *convenient*.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have been to the link(3) you mentioned and thought that there should be more information out there but from what I gather there isn't really much on this topic. I'm aware of examples and vignettes and they are all really useful tools in guiding a user through a package. I'm thinking of combining all three which might be useful from a UX perspective (idk)? My aim is to help my users get hacking with my package without even opening any new tabs, and vignettes will be there if they need more detailed explanations. Well, I'll try and see.

Comment: Vignettes and examples would typically be enough for that, but if you're willing to go the extra mile there's no reason not to put in a demo. The link is just Wickham's summary of demos, there isn't much about them in official R literature or in the language documentation so the best way to do it may be to base your demo folder off of one from a package who's demos you admire.